# How to fetch values from local storage and display it in a disabled input box angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have stored my api_key in local storage . now i wanted to retrieve and show that key in a input box in another html page and that box should show the key stored in local storage . and the field which shows the key should be disabled

> Code for storing the values in local storage

```
 angular
  .module('MyApp', []);

angular
  .module('MyApp')
  .controller('KeyController', [
    '$scope',
    function($scope) {
      /*$scope.info = 'Welcome to Test';*/
      /*console.log(" Key controller is working ");*/
      $scope.api_url;
      $scope.api_token;
      $scope.savedApiUrl = '';
      $scope.savedApiToken = '';

      $scope.submit = function() {
        localStorage.setItem('api_url', $scope.api_url);
        localStorage.setItem('api_token', $scope.api_token);

        var savedApiUrl = localStorage.getItem('api_url');
        var savedApiToken = localStorage.getItem('api_token');
        $scope.savedApiUrl = savedApiUrl;
        $scope.savedApiToken = savedApiToken;
        console.log($scope.savedApiUrl);
        console.log($scope.savedApiToken)
      }
    }
  ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is link to codepen that you can refer.

https://codepen.io/vishwa-/pen/YVaGmR?editors=1011

```
    <div ng-app="MyApp"  ng-controller="KeyController">
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Title</label>
        <input ng-model="savedApiToken" ng-disabled="true">
    </md-input-container>
  </div>
```